# How to return multiple optional values in a python function?

Tags: python

I have a function that should return at least one output, and should return optional values depending on how I set the flag. For example:

```
def foo(a, b, f1=False, f2=False, f3=False):
    c = a + b
    if f1:
        d = a - b
    elif f2:
        e = a * b
    elif f3:
        f = a / b

    if f1:
        return c, d
    elif f2:
        return c, e
    elif f3:
        return c, f
    elif f1 and f2:
        return c, d, e
    elif f1 and f3:
        return c, d, f
    elif f2 and f3:
        return c, e, f
    elif f1 and f2 and f3:
        return c, d, e, f
    else:
        return c
```

If I have `f1, f2, ..., fn` as inputs, I will need to write `2**n` `return`. That can be too many. Is there a better way to handle it? The example code is corrected according to @Tim Roberts' comments.

Comment: Return a `list`?

Comment: Do not write `f1 & f2`.  This is not C.  In Python, you write `f1 and f2`.  The two are NOT interchangeable.

Comment: ＠Tim Roberts Thanks.

Comment: @Masklinn I still have to write many `if `statement to return different outputs

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written it, you will never get multiple results.  Only ONE of the if/elif/elif sequence will be used.

```
def foo(a, b, f1=False, f2=False, f3=False):
    answer = [a + b]
    if f1:
        answer.append( a - b )
    if f2:
        answer.append( a * b )
    if f3:
        answer.append( a / b )
    return answer
```